# How to Add custom row at the end of datagridview in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Above is the snap of how I want to show the list of employees.I was able to show the list of employees but not able to add the last row which shows the grand salary.I am using DataGridView control available in WindowsForms.

Comment: See this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51889/Summary-DataGridView